# Culture variant DaylightName and StandardName (DateTime formatting)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting, culture

I am formatting a DateTime structure like so:

```
"Thu Aug 29 2013 21:46:26 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"
```

Easy enough to get the culture variants for "Thu" and "Aug", but when I test in different languages (*I tested spanish and french*), the string still contains "GMT Daylight Time"

Is it possible to get:

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName` and `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName`

in  different languages?

Comment: Time zone names are stored in the registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones key.  You'd need a localized version of Windows to see something different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Hans Passant** for this answer.

> Time zone names are stored in the registry,
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
>   Zones key. You'd need a localized version of Windows to see something
>   different.